# Issues loading file for iOS Content Blocker

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios9, xcode7

I'm trying to load a file I've save for my iOS Content blocker but I keep getting this log and it won't work. This is my code and log I'm getting, can someone please help me find the issue?

Thanks

Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.apple.SafariServices.ContentBlockerLoader" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.SafariServices.ContentBlockerLoader})

```
import UIKit
import MobileCoreServices

class ActionRequestHandler: NSObject, NSExtensionRequestHandling {

    func beginRequestWithExtensionContext(context: NSExtensionContext) {
        let attachment = NSItemProvider(contentsOfURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("blockerList", withExtension: "json"))!

        let item = NSExtensionItem()
        item.attachments = [attachment]


        if let urlToFile = BlackListManager.sharedInstance.urlToFile(), userFile = NSItemProvider(contentsOfURL: urlToFile) {
            item.attachments = [userFile]
        }

        print(item.attachments)

        context.completeRequestReturningItems([item], completionHandler: { expired in
            print("%@", expired)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Nick, you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck code coverage from schemes then work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).